# Discriminating union of known values combined with mapped type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a class that takes a parameter that can be one of several types. Here's a slightly simplified version:

```
interface KafkaConfig {
  sasl?: SASLOptions
}

enum SASLMechanisms {
  Plain = 'plain',
  ScramSHA256 = 'scram-sha-256',
  ScramSHA512 = 'scram-sha-512',
  AWS = 'aws',
}

type SASLMechanismOptionsMap = {
  [SASLMechanisms.Plain]: { username: string, password: string },
  [SASLMechanisms.ScramSHA256]: { username: string, password: string },
  [SASLMechanisms.ScramSHA512]: { username: string, password: string },
  [SASLMechanisms.AWS]: { authorizationIdentity: string, accessKeyId: string, secretAccessKey: string, sessionToken?: string }
}

type SASLMechanism = keyof SASLMechanismOptionsMap
type SASLMechanismOptions<T> = T extends SASLMechanism ? { mechanism: T } & SASLMechanismOptionsMap[T] : never
type SASLOptions = SASLMechanismOptions<SASLMechanism>
```

Essentially, I'm using the `mechanism` field to determine which shape I expect the options to have, by looking them up in `SASLMechanismOptionsMap`. This means that if I set `mechanism` to `aws`, the compiler can tell me that I need to set `authorizationIdentity` etc.

```
const config: KafkaConfig = {
  sasl: {
    mechanism: 'plain',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
  }
}

// Will not compile because password is missing
const invalidConfig: KafkaConfig = {
  sasl: {
    mechanism: 'plain',
    username: 'username'
  }
}
```

Now I am extending this to allow people to plug in their own SASL mechanisms, which means that if the `mechanism` doesn't match any of the options in `SASLMechanismOptionsMap`, it should fall back to `Record<string, any>`, since I don't know what the expected options will be for custom mechanisms.

What I thought would work would be to add a `[mechanism: string]` property to `SASLMechanismOptionsMap`, like so:

```
type SASLMechanismOptionsMap = {
  [SASLMechanisms.Plain]: { username: string, password: string },
  [SASLMechanisms.ScramSHA256]: { username: string, password: string },
  [SASLMechanisms.ScramSHA512]: { username: string, password: string },
  [SASLMechanisms.AWS]: { authorizationIdentity: string, accessKeyId: string, secretAccessKey: string, sessionToken?: string },
  [mechanism: string]: Record<string, any>
}
```

The problem now is that if I specify a known mechanism with invalid values, that will still match the last type (`[mechanism: string]: Record<string, any>`), and you no longer get any help from the compiler when using one of the known mechanisms.

What I would like to achieve is that if the `mechanism` is set to one of the known mechanisms, the value is required to match the corresponding type, but if the `mechanism` is set to some other value, the value can be anything that matches `Record<string, any>`. Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to implement a 'fallback' like you suggested. As you noticed, the type `[mechanism: string]: Record<string, any>` will apply to any property, even the ones explicitly specified.

You could add an `isCustom` property and discriminate the union on that too so that when it's set, the mechanism can be anything.

But really, falling back to some open type probably isn't a great way to do it - you want your library consumers to be able to be typesafe too! I'd use declaration merging to allow users to add properties to the interface:

```
// LIBRARY CODE

interface KafkaConfig {
  sasl?: SASLOptions
}

enum SASLMechanisms {
  Plain = 'plain',
  ScramSHA256 = 'scram-sha-256',
  ScramSHA512 = 'scram-sha-512',
  AWS = 'aws',
}

interface SASLMechanismOptionsMap {
  [SASLMechanisms.Plain]: { username: string, password: string },
  [SASLMechanisms.ScramSHA256]: { username: string, password: string },
  [SASLMechanisms.ScramSHA512]: { username: string, password: string },
  [SASLMechanisms.AWS]: { authorizationIdentity: string, accessKeyId: string, secretAccessKey: string, sessionToken?: string }
}

type SASLMechanism = keyof SASLMechanismOptionsMap
type SASLMechanismOptions<T> = T extends SASLMechanism ? { mechanism: T } & SASLMechanismOptionsMap[T] : never
type SASLOptions = SASLMechanismOptions<SASLMechanism>

// USER CODE 

interface SASLMechanismOptionsMap {
  "my-mechanism": { myProp1: string, myProp2: string }
}

const config: KafkaConfig = {
  sasl: {
    mechanism: SASLMechanisms.Plain,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
  }
}

const alternativeConfig: KafkaConfig = {
  sasl: {
    mechanism: "my-mechanism",
    myProp1: "",
    myProp2: ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Especially the part about having users do declaration merging to extend the interface, to allow custom mechanisms to have type safety too. For reference, here's what I ended up doing: https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/pull/1101/files#diff-093ad82a25aee498b11febf1cdcb6546e4d223ffcb49ed69cc275ac27ce0ccceR48-R105